# Client side changes of div title are not being reflected in C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a problem with my div element title. The following is my div element:

```
<div id="sampleDiv" runat="server" class="exStyle" onclick="return div_Click(this);" title="any"></div>
```

The following is my javascript:

```
function div_Click(btn) {
    if (btn.title == "any") {
        btn.title = "on";
        btn.style.background = "url('sample1.png')";
    }
    else if (btn.title == "on") {
        btn.title = "off";
        btn.style.background = "url('sample2.png')";
    }
    else if (btn.title == "off") {
        btn.title = "any";
        btn.style.background = "url('sample3.png')";
    }
    return false;
}
```

and after changing the title to "on" or "off" from client side, the value of `Attributes["title"]` from c# code behind is still "any"!! Any help guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Since title is attribute it is never posted back to server. Only input element are posted back to server. There fore you are unable to get the changed value.

To bypassthis restriction you will have to add hiddenfield with runat server tag. update hiddenfield value to the div title before post and recover the value in your code behind by using hiddenfield. value.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this will help you

```
$('#sampleDiv').click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('title') == "any") {
        $(this).prop('title',"on");
        $(this).prop('background,url(sample1.png)');
    }
    else if ($(this).prop('title') == "on") {
         $(this).prop('title',"off");
        $(this).prop('background,url(sample2.png)');
    }
    else if ($(this).prop('title') == "off") {
         $(this).prop('title',"any");
        $(this).prop('background,url(sample3.png)');
    }
});
```

fiddle  [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/XhnWg/2/)

Comment: Can you please post the C# way to access the div title too except Attributes["title"]...which is what I wanted??

Comment: <div id="myDiv" runat="server"> </div> myDiv.Attributes["title"] = "some title";

Comment: first your add runnat tag in div because in c# every element only access by it.. then use myDiv.Attributes["title"] = "some title"; for put value in div title and to get myDiv.Attributes["title"] in some vatiable

Comment: Is this benefit for you?

Comment: Tried everything and no use my friend! Still the title remains as it is when I m trying to access the value from c# code behind...In the UI it is getting effected means the tool tip is getting changed but based on that tip I am returning a boolean which is not getting its value!

Comment: if (myDiv.Attributes["title"] != "any") return myDiv.Attributes["title"] == "on";else            return null; This always returns null

Comment: can you clearify me in which part of cs where you want to get the title of div

Comment: browse never post div and table back to the server.... so you cant get the value. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7638319/823161

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a switch statement here. It will break if there is a match

```
 function div_Click(btn) {
     btn=$(btn);
     switch(btn.attr('title'))
        {
        case 'any':
          btn.attr('title','on');
          btn.css('background','url(sample1.png)');
          break;
        case 'on':
          btn.attr('title','off');
          btn.css('background','url(sample2.png)');
          break;
        case 'off':
          btn.attr('title','on');
          btn.css('background','url(sample3.png)');
          break;
        default:
          //default code if no match
        }
    }
```