# Why can the row in a HTML table not be read from code behind (vb.net)?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, dom, html-table

I have an HTML table and insert a row using Javascript via the `onclick` event of a button.

[image: This is my table]

This is my code.

HTML:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<table id="PopTable" class="imagetable" runat = "server" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>ShipTo</th>
        <th>CustName</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Dari</th>
        <th>Ke</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function AddRow(Shipid,custname, grup, valid, alamat)
{
    var temp11;
    valid = "YES";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrloc.length; i++)
    {
        temp11 = arrloc[i];
        if (Shipid == temp11){ valid = "No" };
    }
    if (valid == "YES"){
        var table = document.getElementById("PopTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        if (grup == "")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "DK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LK";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LJ";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LD";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LP";
            option2.value = "5";
            element2.add(option2, null); }
        else if (grup == "DK")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "LK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LJ";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LD";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LP";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);}
        else if (grup == "LK")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "DK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LJ";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LD";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LP";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);}
        else if (grup == "LJ")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "DK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LK";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LD";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LP";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);}
        else if (grup == "LD")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "DK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LJ";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LK";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LP";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);}
        else if (grup == "LP")
        {
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.innerHTML = "DK";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LJ";
            option2.value = "2";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LD";
            option2.value = "3";
            element2.add(option2, null);
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = "LK";
            option2.value = "4";
            element2.add(option2, null);}


        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "checkbox";

        cell5.innerHTML = grup;
        cell4.innerHTML = alamat;
        cell6.appendChild(element2);
        cell2.innerHTML = Shipid;
        cell3.innerHTML = custname;
        cell1.appendChild(element3);

        arrloc.push(Shipid);}
    }
```

In the code-behind I try to get the contents of the table:

```
For i = 0 To PopTable.Rows.Count

    shipid = PopTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).InnerText
    'shipid = PopTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).innerhtml -- i also try this

    stringsql = "insert into cs_graph_ubah_dklk_log (shipid, dklk_awal, dklk_ubah, tgl_ubah, user_name, flag_proses, mid ) values ('" & shipid & "', '" & dklk_awal & "','" & dklk_ubah & "', sysdate , '" & user & "', 1, cs_graph_ubah_dklk_seq.nextval ) "
    dtsql = SPKOraConnGetDataWS.CreateDataSet(stringsql)

Next
```

I try to insert the HTML table rows via Javascript, but in VB.NET the result is that `rows.count` only has 1 row, and the row is only the header. Why is this happening? On the client-side, Javascript successfully adds rows to the table.

Why does the code-behind only read the header row? What is missing?

Please ask if you need more information from me.

Comment: I can't help but notice that you are using `Rows(1)` rather than `Rows(i)` in the VB. Anyway, you can't change HTML with Javascript just like that; the changes won't be passed back to the server on submit. Put the data also in the value or a hidden input or something.

Comment: okay i will find another ways .. thanks.

Comment: I see I had a typo, I meant the value _of_ a hidden input of course. `<input type="hidden" runat="server">`, and using Javascript fill its value attribute. (Don't use Javascript to create a new `<input>` from scratch and give t a `runat` attribute.)

Comment: follow this post: [How to post table rows, added via Javascript, to the server in ASP.NET?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638272/how-to-post-table-rows-added-via-javascript-to-the-server-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

the main reason can be fured out by post in the comment by  Amir Sherafatian:

when the website is created, all html is rendered  - the elements that have runat="server" attribute have 1:1 objects generated sever side during page execution.

Mind you, page execution ends when the html is written to the client and then  unless you store some data in Cache /Session/ ViewState/ cookies or any other persistent storage all the data regarding the rendered page is lost on the web server.

when client clicks submit the state of the page is recovered from those persistent storages and inputs that are on the webpage (which is basically a form hence every postback sends ALL inputs / selects / hidden fields back to the server) Imagine, that the user modifies your page via own java script using console - it simply cannot be accepted bu the server. the html means nothing to the web server on postbacks. The only mean of communication is via postback attributes which are mapped from form fields.

any other objects that are not input fields / hidden fields are rebuild from the aspx/html (on your server) somewhere along begining page execution.

Your code behind sees only header row because only header row is defined in the table from which the state of the page is built.

if you want to achieve your goal, you need to define at least one hidden field with runat=server"  to which you'd add / remove data as you add / remove rows with JavaScript. Its data will then be sent as a form postback argument to the server. There you can access it just like accessing a hidden field (as i explained the hidden field value will be rebuild from postback arguments), read the data, parse it and do whatever you want.

If you want a sample code ( ASP.Net C#),  please shout :)