# How to get html table values in code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have one HTML table. In the table I added a tr during run-time using the javascript code below -

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var tab_length= table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(tab_length);
row.id="Row"+tab_length;
var Ord_ID = row.insertCell(0);
var Ord_Name = row.insertCell(1);
var Ord_Qty = row.insertCell(2);
var Ord_Price = row.insertCell(3);
var Ord_Total = row.insertCell(4);
var Del_Button = row.insertCell(5);
var Edit_Button = row.insertCell(6);    
Ord_ID.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Ord_ID").value;
Ord_Name.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Ord_Name").value;
Ord_Qty.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Ord_Qty").value;
Ord_Price.innerHTML = document.getElementById("Ord_Price").value;
```

But I can not access the tr values in c#. Can anyone please help with this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to access the values in C#?

Comment: tablename.rows[][] like this

Comment: Keep in mind that the server is not aware of what is done on the client side, you have to specifically send it to the server. Are these new values generated 100% client-side?

Comment: Surprise! How come he didn't get the state validation error?

Comment: @Andrew yes the new values are created in client side . u r correct ...

Comment: @ vendettamit i have added runar="server" in table code.

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638272/how-to-post-table-rows-added-via-javascript-to-the-server-in-asp-net

Comment: And here you have a cool explanation of why this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396534/why-can-the-row-in-a-html-table-not-be-read-from-code-behind-vb-net

Comment: @BaskarVijayan, could you try something of what I commented?

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery to send an Ajax POST request. If you want to do error handling, you can return either a success or error message in JSON format. Have a look at this link for more information:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/