# Transfer values from HTML Table back to Codebehind on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET (4.5) page with a table on it, each row of the table has several fields along with a checkbox, I already have a java function in place to determine which checkboxes are ticked and return that information back to the vb.net code for processing via a hidden field. I now need to be able to send the value of another field in the table back along with the selected check box Id, I have no idea how.

So I'm looking for my hidden field to eventually look like:

chkboxID1,otherfield1,chkboxID2,otherfield2,..etc.

My current code is:

```
<script>
function test() {
    var idSelector = function () { return this.id; };
    var bChecked = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
    document.getElementById('<%=shortlists.ClientID%>').value = bChecked;
}
</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="submit" value="Shortlist" onclick="test();" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="shortlists" runat="server" />
```

The table I want to extract the data from is:

```
<table id="shortlist" class="compact" style="text-align: center;">
<thead style="text-align: center">
    <tr>
   <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Details</th>
   <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center">Stats</th>
       <th colspan="3" style="text-align: center">Overall</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center">Date/Time</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">League</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Fixture</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">P</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">ALL</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">L2</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">LP +-2</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Avg FHG</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Rating</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Checkbox</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
   <td>23/12/2015 19:30:00</td>
   <td>Serie B</td>
   <td>Pescara v Modena</td>
   <td>18</td>
   <td>44.44</td>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>33.33</td>
   <td>2.56</td>
   <td>34</td>
   <td><input id=357701 type="checkbox" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>23/12/2015 19:30:00</td>
   <td>Serie B</td>
   <td>Pro Vercelli v Perugia</td>
   <td>19</td>
   <td>31.58</td>
   <td>50</td>
   <td>25</td>
   <td>1.84</td>
   <td>36</td>
   <td><input id=357702 type="checkbox" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get the ID of the selected checkbox and the value of the 'Rating' column, so from this example (providing both checkboxes are ticked) I would want my hidden field to read:

```
357701,34,35702,36
```

Comment: you can do it with ajax, json

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638272/how-to-post-table-rows-added-via-javascript-to-the-server-in-asp-net

Comment: Is there any reason to process a hidden field filled in by js rather than just processing the submitted inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `asp:Button` call your `javascript function` in `OnClientClick` and your `code behind function` in `OnClick` function.

It will first call your `javascript` function and then it will call your `code behind` function.

```
<script>
function test() {
var idSelector = function () { return this.id; };
var bChecked = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
//To store multiple values
bChecked = bChecked + ",AnotherFeild";
document.getElementById('<%=shortlists.ClientID%>').value = bChecked;
}
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" OnClientClick="test()" OnClick="btntest_Click" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="shortlists" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btntest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string val = shortlists.Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I already know how to do this, my question is how do I collect another value from the table along with the checkbox Id?

Comment: What do you mean by another ? Just store it in another `hiddenfeild` .

Comment: Or if you want to store all values of a row in one hiddenfeild than make a variable and store values in it and assign hiddenfeild to this variable.

Comment: I tried this but just ended up with chkboxID1,chkboxID2,FieldHeading. I don't think this is going to be possible actually as there is no way to reference the field and relate it to the checkboxID.

Comment: Please post the code from which you want the other values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if the checkbox is checked, and if it is, obtain its id, and the value of the field next to it.

If so, set the checkbox and the other field you want to obtain the value from to `runat="server"`,then when the user clicks the button, go through all your checkboxes, and if they are checked, get the value held in the field you want:

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
{
//Get the value from the cell you want
}
```

NOTE:I do not think you can use a number as an ID, but you could store the it in the `name` field or possibly give it an ID like `checkbox|357701`, and then split the id once you work out if it is checked